# AppIcon React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

Can someone help me with setting up AppIcon in the application which was generated with create-react-native-app. There is no any native code. 
P.S. AppIcon is the main icon which you tap to start the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for android
- goto android folder -> app-> src-> main-> res
- Replace ic_launcher icon in all midmap folders

Comment: create-react-native-app doesn't provide any source code and folder for each platfrom.

Answer (score 0):

When using `create-react-native-app` you're creating a new application using Expo framework. You can change the application icon by configuring your app via app.json. Here's the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html#iconlocal-path-or-remote-url-to-an-image-to-use-for-your-apps-icon-we-recommend-that-you-use-a-1024x1024-png-file-this-icon-will-appear-on-the-home-screen-and-within-the-expo-app

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try.